# Same domain Policy exceptions?

Tags: ajax, same-origin-policy

When i make an ajax call from my localhost to this url (Geo data) http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON i do not get block by the same origine Policy. How come ? I thought this was a client sided lock. Is this because the data received is JSON ?

Answer (score 1):

This is thanks to [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control) or `CORS`.

In the HTTP header response, geonames.org is setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`.

That allows any origin, including localhost or stackoverflow.com

To see it in action, try this code out in Chrome (right click->Inspect Element is one way to pop the console) and then inspect the "Network" tab for the request headers:

```
jQuery.ajax( {
     url: 'http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON'
     , success: function(e){ console.log( "Success!", e ); }
     , error: function(e){ console.log( "Error.", e ); }
);
```